# Multiplayer Entities And Player Storage Systems

Tags: multiplayer, godot, mmo, minecraft-modding, storage

https://github.com/Zylann/voxelgame/issues/103 How can entities and player storage work for this demo? Are there any examples or prototypes?

Goal: Minecraft style entity and player storage system. Bonus account system.

How can entities and storage system like chests stored in chunk data like minecraft? Bonus for account linked storage like M.M.O. player inventory and banks / minecraft player account inventory with shulker boxes.

Comment: While you are looking for how to save entities in particular with this very pecific code base. I would suggest you to look into how to save *anything*. If you look for how to save and load arbitrary data, you might find solutions that you could adapt.